# Odoo extend website_sale JS function

Tags: javascript, inheritance, odoo, extend

Hello I'd like to inherit on the following function **$shippingDifferent.change(function (event) {** under **website_sale.js** in order to add the following piece of code in it:

```
if (value == 1) {
        value = 0   
}
```

I know how to include or extend a Module but here there is no module, so any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

First of all i would suggest you one line:

> Never ever use the `website_sale.js` for the purpose of reference.

As it's contain  raw j query  instead of backbone.js .

You can't use the concept of `include` and `extend` Like:

```
var website_sale = require('website_sale.website_sale');
   website_sale.include({
     include_my_task: function() {
        var self = this;
         // body of  logic to be included ...

        },
    });

   website_sale.extend({
     override_prev_task: function() {
       var self = this;
       this._super();
       // body of  logic to be extended ...

     },
   });
```

Below i am posting some j query based code snippet, it's may help you.

```
   $(document).ready(function() 
 {   
      odoo.define("website_sale.website_sale", function (require) 
      {
            "use strict";
            $(".oe_website_sale").each(function () {
             var oe_website_sale = this;
                function do_my_task (event) {
                        // body...
                }

                $(oe_website_sale).on("click", "span.my_class",do_my_task );

           });
      }
});
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer, so I entered everything from the original file + my code were you type "//body...", but he doesn't seem to find this piece of code, since he ingores my code.. I added the reference to this file in my xml template (so I know 100% he can find the file)

Comment: first of all just test by alert , place alert("Test1"); before  odoo.define("website_sale.website_sale", function (require)   and alert("Test2") after var oe_website_sale = this;  ,see whether you   are seeing the both alert or not ,